# Indication that someone else is editing

Tags: feature-request, editing

Is there a way to see whether someone else has started editing a post?  There are times that I'd like to fix a post, but don't want to duplicate someone else's effort or overwrite any edits they made, or whatever happens on a conflict.

Tom O'Connor recently asked about [Some kind of 'edit locking'](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3251/some-kind-of-edit-locking).  To be clear, I'm not asking for locking, just an indication that someone started editing the post already.

Comment: I knew it was *you* that stole those precious `/review` edits from me!

Comment: @jscott: Bwah-ha-HA-HA-ha!

Comment: The concept of an indicator has all the same problems as a lock. If one was practical so the other would be. I'm not saying either is a bad idea, just that I can't see them being workable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does already; unfortunately it takes a long time. The edit screen auto-saves your drafts every few minutes; when it does so it sees if anyone else has a draft being auto-saved. Unfortunately that means the other person has to have been editing long enough to auto-save, or be done editing themself, and you have to have been editing long enough to auto save, then it will appear.

Comment: How about autosaving immediately upon starting to edit?